# May I stack prepositions: "somewhere inside of me"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Today I heard a song, where were the words:
'I feel eternity somewhere inside of me'

I've never heard it before and I'm interesting is it right construction?
By the way, in many songs I hear very strange sentence structure...

Answer (score 4):

It is very common to use multiple locative expressions to specify a location more precisely. There's a famous Chuck Berry song, "Memphis, Tennessee", which contains three successive locatives:

> Her home is [on the southside] [high up on the ridge]
>   [Just a half a mile from the Mississippi bridge].

We do the same thing with temporal locatives

> Nelson died at half-past four, three hours after he had been shot.

Just as with chained adjectives (*a big round red ball*), it is often difficult to decide whether any given locative in a chain modifies another locative or co-modifies some other term. The effect is vaguely cumulative: *somewhere inside me* means, approximately, "at some point which I know to be inside me but  cannot specify more precisely".